# Pairs of strings in reverse order in a list of more than million strings?

Tags: string, reverse

Recently asked during some interview that "How to find reverse of all strings if exists in a list of more than million strings?

For E.g.   str[1] = "abc", I need to check for "cba" exactly, no anagrams.

Method 1. Store all the strings in a hashset, start traversing from the first string and check for the reversed form exists in Hashset. if yes, then pair else move to next element.

Can you suggest any method if memory is the constraint?

Comment: On re-reading it's not clear whether you want to find all strings that are reverses of others in the same list, or, given a string, find a string in the list that's its reverse.  The latter, of course, is a simple search problem, after you reverse the given string.

Comment: Although I agree with Daniel on that, considering MEMORY as a constraint, that wouldn't matter at all.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I have edited my question.... he meant that for all the strings in the list find if there exists a reverse of it...

Answer (score 4):

If allowed, you could in-place sort the strings so when you look up the reverse of a string you can do a binary search.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) which will tell you if a string already exists within a hash table like structure, but each bucket is only 0 or 1 so very little space is used.

Exactly 1 000 000 bits == 125 KB

Comment: 1.) this will take more memory. 2) you don't need long string to get a lot of them with the same length.

Answer (score 1):

First I would hash the strings using a hash that was independent of direction.  This could be a simple sum of characters, though there are certainly better schemes that would hash from both ends.  And to "sweeten the deal" one could append string length to the hash value, or otherwise incorporate it in the hash.

Then when you have the strings broken into identical hash groups, do the "long hand" compare.

Note that, using either this scheme or the one where you simply use a direction dependent hash forwards or backwards, the thing to do is to not immediately insert the string into the hash set, but rather check it (with the reversed hash if needed) first, and if you get a match (and the subsequent long compare is true) remove the already-hashed string and pair the two.  The second string never goes into the set, and, if all the strings have matches at most you'd only ever have 500,000 entries in the hash set, and, if the strings were random, probably closer to 250,000 (I haven't sat down to figure the probabilities).

So you'd need only one pass through the set of strings to do the whole thing.

Comment: doing a direction independent hash value doesn't give you any real benefits but will certainly increase the collision ratio.

Comment: The direction-independent hash hashes "abc" and "cba" into the same bucket.  This greatly reduces the number of combinations you have to try.

Comment: I don't get it. Why does it reduce anything? What combinations are you talking about?

Comment: With this scheme one only needs to compare strings with the same hash.  I'd guess that you could arrange to get at least 5000 distinct hashes, so that the average number of strings you'd have to compare to another would be on the order of 200, vs 1,000,000.  And a little effort might yield a hash algorithm that would do much better than that.

Comment: You mean you want to generate a lot of hash collisions? What's the point of that? You need a linked list to store the results, so you won't use less memory, but because of the collisions definitely use more CPU. In that case I prefer the OP's solution as it's superior.

Comment: *censored*. I did and shared with you my concerns.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>With "**memory as a constraint**" then I wouldn't even go for a HashSet (which, afaik will also remove the duplicated strings in the original list) because you'll be using the additional structure of a HashSet which takes some memory.</strike>

Sorting, wouldn't improve memory usage either.

I would use the original list (which is already there, so no extra memory will be used) + a 3 byte integer variable to iterate the list. 3 bytes can iterate over a list of 2^24 = 16777216 strings

With "**memory as a constraint**" I would go for 2 for loops. I think a C-Like pseudocode will be easier to understand that my plain english.

Notes:

1. From the example provided in the question, it is not actually a List but an Array, so I will operate over the structure as if it was an Array
2. The question is not clear whether how to pair this "abc","def","cba","abc". I will be pairing the first "abc" with "cba" and also that "cba" with "the second "abc" (the intention is unclear in the question)
3. I assume we can't modify the original list

Here is the least memory-consumption code I can think of:

```
// "list" holds the original list (array)
for (int i = 0; i < length(list) - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < length(list); j++) {
        if (list[i] == reverse(list[j])) {
            print(list[i] + " reversed is " list[j])
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding memory usage, this solution will take 2 integer variables (usually 4 bytes each) + the original list, which I assume we can not get rid of.

Regarding CPU usage (actually, not relevant based on the question), the amount of times a strings will be reversed will be: (N*(N+1))/2 where N is the length of the list

Comment: 1,000,000,000,000 iterations, more or less.  (Not counting the actual compare loop.)

Comment: Hmm, no. Just 1 iteration over the list. The order of this solution is N. But as I stated and the person who asked clearly stated, there is no need to do it fast but with the least amount of memory. The list is already there I'm just adding 3 bytes. How many additional bytes does your solution take?

Comment: So please explain how, in one pass through the list, you identify all the reversed duplicates in the list.

Comment: Daniel you're last comment made me understand the original question. I thought, like in the example in the question, you already had a string and that the idea was to check whether the reverse form of that (single) string was contained in the list. Absolutely my bad. Removing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose HashTable and use buckets to reduce hash conflict. What we now need to do for a specific query string is just reverse it, hash it and find in the HashTable instead of traverse from start to then end.

Comment: Yeah, this is essentially the same as my scheme, only with twice as many hashes.

Answer (score 1):

This is jus my opinion:

I would create a hash with

***key=character***

***value=List of string which start with that character***

- Now start a loop inside which you need to start at the first string.
- reverse it
- Take the first character and search for that key in the hash
- then in the value of that,it contains the list of strings and find the string in that list